# Why do I receive 'SMTPServerDisconnected' while trying to send and email through Python?

Tags: python, email, smtp, port, smtplib

I utilize my Android phone to send a simple email message through coding in python. Here is the code:

```
import os
import smtplib
EMAIL_ADDRESS =os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD =os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
   
  smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
  subject = 'Practice email code'
  body = 'This is my 1st output'

  msg = f'Subject:{subject}\n{body}'

smtp.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_ADDRESS, msg)
```

Here is the traceback I've got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File                            "/data/user/0          ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in 
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  **main**.**dict**)
File "", line 7, in 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in **init**
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
(code, msg) = self.getreply()
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

EDIT: When I tried 587 port, this is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 12, in 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 638, in auth
authobject(challenge).encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in 
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  **main**.**dict**)
File "", line 19, in 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 280, in **exit**
raise SMTPResponseException(code, message)
smtplib.SMTPResponseException: (334, b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6')

I appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way of using SMTP

```
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('EMAIL', 'PASSWORD')
    server.sendmail('EMAIL to send from',to, msg)
    server.close()
```

And also, your email should allow external sources to access your email making it less safe so I recommend using an extra email for this

Comment: Thank you for this! Have succesfully sent an email. But why is it that the with statement could not do the process? The code written above is just a paste of what I've found online, so for others it does work well. And it is also cleaner because you don't need to manually close the server.

Comment: If the answer works you are supposed to take it as an answer. There should be a tick mark next to this